# Developing Web Services Using Spring-Integration

Tags: java, web-services, spring-integration, spring-ws, endpoints

I have had experience developing web services using Spring-WS before. 
However, I was wondering if I can develop a web service purely using Spring-Integration using Inbound Gateways etc. 
If you have experience developing Web-Services using Spring-Integration, can you please provide me some guidance and also provide some references?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the good point to start is [Spring Integration samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/ws-inbound-gateway)

There is no nothing special: you configure Servlet Context as before and add bean:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.UriEndpointMapping">
     <property name="defaultEndpoint" ref="ws-inbound-gateway"/>
</bean>
```

Everything other should be done using EIP components: Routers, Filters, Service-Activators etc.

Another chioce to write service endpoints as before, but delegate hard work to Integration flows using `<int:gateway>`

Comment: Thanks Artem. Let's say that gives me a starting point to begin with and define the endpoint... But to take it further... How do I handle interceptors for implementing security etc... Spring-WS gives ways to add interceptor in the endpoint... Is there something similar tat can be done with Spring Integration? I just want to identify if Spring-WS is still the best way to develop Web Services using Spring or can Spring-Integration ease the task?

Comment: No difference: Spring Integration populates the same `MessageEndpoint`, so you can continue to configure (or reuse) all other Spring WS infrastructure